How is memory allocated to class object and it's data members in C++
So we have 2 main memories stack and heap. When I create an simple object of class(A obj) which is heap allocated and if we have data members which require heap allocation and stack allocation then what does actually happens? How much memory is allocated on heap while creating object and are stack allocated data members excluded from this heap allocation for object.
class A{
   public:

   int height;
   int * weight;

   A(){
     height=0;
     weight= new int(100);
   }
};

int main(){
  A *obj = new A(); // what's the memory allocation for object

  return 0;
}

My assumption is when we create heap allocated object then data members which require stack allocation are stack allocated and not counted for object's memory allocation on heap and other data members which require heap allocation are heap allocated and are consider for objects memory allocation. So in above allocation we only need 4bytes of heap memory as only have single data member which is pointer.

Please note that new int(100) creates one single int value, and initializes it to 100.

As for your question, because you use new A() all of the object data (its member variables) will be located on the heap. And on a modern 64-bit system a pointer is usually 64 bits, i.e. 8 bytes. Together with the int variable height (assuming a size of 4 bytes) and probable padding between the variables (for alignment), the size of your class should be 16 bytes.

So does it mean if object is stack allocated then 'height' var would be stored on stack and if object is heap allocated it will be stored on heap.

Yes, the data of the object will be located where it's allocated. If you have A obj; then the object and both its member variables will be located in automatic memory (like. the stack).

Data members don’t get to choose where they are allocated. The memory for them has already been allocated when the memory for the containing object is allocated

OPh and a very important distinction: With A* obj = new A(); you actually allocate two things: The first is the variable obj itself, which will be stored in automatic memory (the stack), and the variable will be initialized to point to an instance of A which is allocated on the heap.

So that's one of the ways to store data on heap without using new keyword.Interesting!

Yes gotcha programmer dude!

Your code shouldn't really care about where object member variables are stored.

we have 2 main memories stack and heap. -- This is misunderstanding of the memory concept. The both member variables are located in A storage. One of them points to a heap allocated memory after initialization of A. See Member model

I know that both are on RAM.xd

Remember, there is another place that variables can exist:  global memory.  The global memory is where static and file global variables get placed.  So if you declare an object static or place it outside of a function, it will be allocated in the global memory.

in "C++" do NOT use pointers when you need an array, use std::vector. E.g. std::vector<int> weight(10). See C++ core guidelines ES42. So whoever taught you to do this weight= new int(100); has not been teaching you C++

What about member functions where are they stored? although common for all instances.

Member functions are just "normal functions" with one hidden first this argument (where this is a pointer to the class instance that can either be allocated on stack or on the heap)

Related reading: Stack Memory vs Heap Memory and What and where are the stack and heap?

Does this answer your question: A: Object creation on the stack/heap? The question that answers looks like a near duplicate, but I'm not sure enough to one-vote close this as a duplicate.

There's no such thing as a data member which requires heap allocation (or stack allocation either). Until you drop that misunderstanding you're not going to get very far. In the example you quote above everything is on the heap, (excepting the variable obj) but use A in a different way and this may not be true.

Thinking about this question a little more, it seems like a variation of the common beginner mistake with pointers of failing to distinguish between the pointer and what the pointer is pointing at. In the code above the pointer obj is on the stack, but what it points at is in the heap.

That is a really good question. The initialization in C++ is the most complicated topic, so do not hesitate to ask questions. Even experienced developers may misunderstand some concepts.
There are no heap data members or stack data members. All the data members inside the class are allocated one by one close to each other's in the order as they are declared in the class.
What you are missing are the pointers. Pointer is similar to the unsigned int data type. It occupies 4 bytes on the 32-bit platform and 8 bytes on the 64-bit platform regardless of the data size it points to. You may think of memory as an array of bytes and pointer is an index to the array.
In order to construct the object you need a storage. You may think of storage as a region in the memory. What is the size of the object? The answer is sizeof(A). On 64 bit platform sizeof(A) == 16

4 bytes for the int variable
4 bytes padding (google it)
8 bytes for the pointer to int

The storage is an addressable memory you can get a pointer:

Platform neutral

static storage (global variables)
dynamic storage (heap)
automatic storage (stack)
thread local storage


Platform specific

memory mapped files
shared memory
maybe more, depends on platform



So when you construct the object on the stack, the compiler allocates the required amount of memory on the stack and invokes the class constructor.
When you construct the object on the heap using the operator new, the compiler invokes a malloc-like function to allocate some amount of the memory on the heap and then it invokes the class constructor.
In case if object is allocated on the stack, compiler ensures it is destroyed once you return from the function (or leave the scope they say). The same behavior is for the objects allocated on the static storage.
In case if object is allocated on the heap, it is developer's responsibility to destroy the object and release the memory.
In your case you perform two allocations on the heap:

One is for the class A object
Another one is for the int

Because you never call operator delete the objects you're created are never released. That is a memory leak.

The terms "heap" and "stack" are not platform-neutral.   In fact, those terms (referring to areas of memory) originated in context of a particular platform, and referred to physically different areas of memory (i.e. on physical memory chips/circuits). The platform neutral counterparts of "heap" and "stack" are "dynamically allocated memory" "variables of automatic storage duration".  Some commonly used implementations (compilers and libraries) default to placing dynamically allocated memory in "heap" and automatic variables (and also static variables, incidentally) in "stack".

the operator new, the compiler invokes malloc() This is not true, this is one of possible but not the only implementation detail.

malloc to allocate some amount of the memory on the stack This is usually unlikely true,

@Peter: The platform neutral counterparts of "heap" and "stack" are "dynamically allocated memory" "variables of automatic storage duration": Fixed. thanks

@3CxEZiVlQ: the compiler invokes malloc() This is not true, this is one of possible but not the only implementation detail: Do you want to explain this guy all the edge cases now?

@3CxEZiVlQ: malloc to allocate some amount of the memory on the stack. Typo. Fixed, thanks

all the edge cases Just don't tell them this information. It gets a storage in a dynamic memory and initializes an object, that's enough. If it was C how would you tell about malloc()?

@3CxEZiVlQ, Those "correct" words make the simple things complicated. For the beginning the information I give should be enough to start


So we have 2 main memories stack and heap

That's a silly thing to say, you just have memory. Be it from single or multiple RAM sticks, L* CPU caches, disk backed memory mapped files, swap files, tape, it's all memory. And the correct name for it is virtual memory in modern operating systems. Whether you choose to name parts of it "stack" or "heap" or "kittens", that's your choice.

So in above allocation we only need 4bytes of heap memory as only have single data member which is pointer.

No, you have sizeof(A) (probably) equal to 2 * sizeof(int). On a 32-bit Intel system, that's (probably) 8 bytes. That's how much memory is allocated by the new operator when called with A.

weight= new int(100);

Unrelated to your question, but that most likely doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't allocate an array of 100 int items, it allocates one int and initializes it to 100.

What about member functions where are they stored?

Functions are code, and code is stored in the text segment of your executable. It is then mapped to virtual memory by the OS executable loader and memory manager, allowing pointers to reference it.
Virtual member functions are different, a pointer to them is stored in a hidden allocation inside your class allocation. Did you happen to see all those "probably" above? The virtual function table is one reason for those, it makes the allocation larger than it would seem to be.

The C++ standard has automatic variables (stack), dynamically allocated variables (heap) and a third category you missed: variables with static storage duration (global).

@RaymondChen Those aren't locations in memory. The C++ standard has automatic, dynamic, static, and thread (which you missed) storage durations. The standard defines how long the storage must endure, but it's up to the implementation to decide where that storage lives. Case in point: inside a co-routine, a variable with automatic storage duration may very well live in heap memory so that the co-routine can suspend.

The standard says nothing about where in memory these objects exist. The distinctions between stack, heap, and global is an implementation detail (though a detail that most implementations agree on). There might be some confusion in the original question over what is part of the language and what is part of the implementation.

That is exactly what I said, stack/heap are implementation details, and very fluid ones (the coroutine example above).
